# In SQL language (AWS timestream) - how to get the latest value of non-grouped by column? (latest - meaning the most recent row)

Tags: sql, amazon-timestream

My goal - is to group my data by a specific field, and select also the latest value from another field on that group.

I have the following table:

```
| type | count | action | time                         |
   a       5      put     2021-04-21 15:13:02.104308224 
   b       7      put2    2021-04-20 15:13:02.104308224 
   b       1      get     2021-04-19 15:13:02.104308224 
   a       4      put6    2021-04-18 15:13:02.104308224 
   c       5      get     2021-04-17 15:13:02.104308224 
   a       6      put     2021-04-17 15:13:02.104308224
```

My statement is as follows:

```
 SELECT
    type,
    SUM(count) as total,
FROM mydb.mytable
WHERE time between ago(1h) and now()
GROUP type
```

I will eventually get the following rows:

```
| type | total
   a      15  
   b      8
   c      5
```

The thing is, I need to add to each row (that was grouped) also the **action** of the most **recent** row - so it should be

```
| type | total | action
   a      15      put
   b      8       put2
   c      5       get
```

how can it be achieved? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if it supports window functions :

```
select 
   type,
   lastaction, 
   SUM(count) as total
  from (
    SELECT   *, 
    first_value(action) over (partition by type order by time desc) lastaction
    FROM mydb.mytable
    WHERE time between ago(1h) and now()
)
GROUP BY type, lastaction
```

Comment: I think it does! but i get the following error:

line 7:39: ORDER BY expression 'time' must be an aggregate expression or appear in GROUP BY clause

Comment: @ArielB how about now?

Comment: Nice! it works nicely :) Thanks for helping a guy that haven't touched SQL for ages :)

Comment: One last question - is it possible to select 2 fields' first_value? without partitioning twice? (which sounds an overhead?) - my workaround is to concat - first_value(CONCAT(action,'#',anothercolumn))

Comment: @ArielB yes , if the window is the same , that should work

Comment: Timestream appears to not support multiple fields, and one more question - is it possible to filter the partition? let's say i have another field which can be "1" "2" or "3", i wanna choose the latest value only for the partitions with the value "2", even if 1 came later?

Comment: @ArielB make a new question for that , with  sample data and desired output